# DynamoDB: filter and sort the same field?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have a table with Local Index like below.

how to make a query like startDate < InvoiceDate < endDate and sort the result descending by InvoiceDateLocalIndex ??

as far as I know, to sort the result I need to using InvoiceDateLocalIndex. But if I'd used , I got the error "Filter Expression can only contain non-primary key attributes: Primary key attribute: InvoiceDate"

```
"IndexName": "InvoiceDateLocalIndex",
 "KeySchema": [
  {
     "AttributeName": "FinanceYear",
     "KeyType": "HASH"
  },
  {
     "AttributeName": "InvoiceDate",
     "KeyType": "RANGE"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you can't use a `FilterExpression` over the range key (`InvoiceDate`). But the reason for that is not that it couldn't be done - the reason why this is forbidden is to prevent you from making a costly mistake:

**To request only a range of your range key, you should use `KeyConditionExpression`, not `FilterExpression`.**

Using `KeyConditionExpression` is faster and cheaper because DynamoDB only retrieves the matching items - whereas `FilterExpression` would read (and charge you) the entire partition. This is why "range keys" are called "range keys" - they allow you to efficiently request a range of this key. They are alternatively called a "sort key" because they don't just do ranges - they are actually sorted.

Comment: could you please give me the example for using KeyConditionExpression to solve my question since im new to dynamoDB and in not familliar with dynamodb query syntax (we use dynamoose)

Comment: KeyConditionExpression has the same syntax as FilterExpression (which I assume you were using), it's just a separate variable, and you need to list the conditions on the key attributes there - not in FilterExpression. The documentation is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html